# How can i group and sum elements in matrix, without using itertools.groupby?

Tags: python

the problem that I am facing is simple. I have matrix as list of lists like this:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

And I want to get is tuple that has grouped occurrences of 1 for rows on one side and for cols on the other. So for the matrix above it would be like this:

```
([[1], [1, 1, 1], [7], [2, 1], [3], [1, 1]],[[1], [2], [1, 2, 1], [4], [1, 2], [1, 1], [3]])
```

As you can see it "sums" adjascent duplicates so list like this [1,0,1,1] would resolve in [[1],[0],[2]]

I tried working on the rows and ended up with this:

```
    for line in matrix:
        new_list = []
        for value in line:
            if new_list and new_list[-1][0] == value:
                new_list[-1].append(value)
            else:
                new_list.append([value])
        result_list.append(new_list)
```

This splits the list into duplicates but does not sum the adjascent and still leaves 0 in the result.

Does anyone have good solution for both rows and colls to achieve my desired Tuple?

PS: I know i could use itertools.groupby but I am trying to solve it without it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in `data`, here you go:

```
def grp(data):
    result = []
    for row in data:
        count = 0
        row_result = []
        for c in row:
            if c==0:
                if count > 0:
                    row_result.append(count)
                    count = 0
            else:
                count += 1
        if count > 0:
            row_result.append(count)
        result.append(row_result)
    return result

data = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], 
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], 
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]]

print((grp(data),grp(zip(*data)))
```

gives me your desired result (using Python 3).

Comment: God bless you and your children! That is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Hey, One more thing please. I have type error. 

`Expected type 'list[list[int]]', got 'Union[Iterator[tuple[Any, ...]], Iterator[tuple[Any, Any, Any, Any, Any]], Iterator[tuple[Any, Any, Any, Any]], Iterator[tuple[Any, Any, Any]], Iterator[tuple[Any, Any]]]' instead.`
I tried manually setting my matrix to List[List[int]] but it did not help.

Comment: I have a question please, What was data matrix you have passed ?

Comment: @AliAlnadous Its List[List[int]] exactly this matrix: 
`[
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    ]`

And the code itself works, Only when I typed it so I changed the head of the function to this:
`def grp(data: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:`
The type error showed up. Seems that zip function does not return List

Comment: Try 'print((grp(matrix))' instead, to ensure it is the error, then try 'print((grp(matrix),grp(list(zip(*matrix)))))'

Comment: The error is only in mypy. So its type error. First part `print(grp(matrix))` is alright but the second, even if I try to List() it, it wont help. It still has this type error: `Expected type 'list[list[int]]', got 'list[tuple[Any, ...]]' instead `

Comment: Maybe try `grp([list(x) for x in zip(*data)])`?